# Dynamic Transfer SQL Server Objects Task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have an SSIS package which uses the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task object. We use the GUI in SSIS to create the object and set it to copy over approx. 200 tables, either by selecting the tables through the 'TablesList' parameter or adding them in the Properties window.

We have the object configured to copy data, and drop the destination first.

Performance wise we transfer these 200 tables in approx. 30 minutes.

We are regularly asked to update the tables we transfer. At the moment someone has alter the package, select the additional tables, deploy etc. so we looked at finding a better way of doing this.

It does not seem like the TablesList is a property we can set via an Expression so went down the route of creating a C# script task to dynamically create a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer object, and add the tables by looping round a list of tables in an Object and adding them one by one. This works fine - however performance is terrible - almost double what we get from the same object created using the GUI, using the same databases and same tables.

I cannot see anything in the Extended Events log which would account for the difference in performance.

Are we destined to have to manually manage the list forever or is this performance issue a known problem or something anyone else has experienced before?